# Oracle SQL: how to search honorofics in a string

Tags: sql, oracle, search, text

I have name fields in my data set. Using Oracle PL SQL, how can I search for the records that contain honorifics?

I have a list of honorifics that I want to search for in a separate table. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please learn how to use the {} 'code sample' editing tool that is located at the top left of the input dialog. Good luck.

Comment: In the name field do they always come in the beginning and always separated from the first name by either `.` (period) or ` ` (space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) and do a cross join against the honorifics table.

This query will list all names that have an honorific, plus the honorific. If a name has more than one honorific it will be listed for each match:

```
SELECT
  myTable.Name,
  honorifics.Title
FROM myTable
CROSS JOIN honorifics
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(myTable.Name, ''(\W|^)' || honorifics.Title || '(\W|$)')
```

The regex checks to see if the honorific title is at the beginning of the string *or* preceded by a "non-word" character, and if it's at the end of the string *or* followed by a non-word character.

Note that this search is case sensitive. To make it non-case sensitive, add a third argument of `'i'` to the `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(myTable.Name, ''(\W|^)' || honorifics.Title || '(\W|$)', 'i')
                                                                         ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful. However, I also have to search for any prefix and suffix which can be somewhere in the middle of the text. Do you know how to add that case to the code you wrote?

Comment: Have you tried the query yet? Despite my confusing explanation, it should find the prefix/suffix anywhere it shows up in the name. The \W and so forth makes sure the honorific is all on its own - for example if you're looking for `Dr` the regex will find it in `Dr John Jones` (where it's a word on its own) but not in `Drew Jones` (where it's part of the name "Drew" and not a word on its own).

Comment: Yes, Thanks again. I think it's pulling all the texts that have prefix and suffix in the middle. However, Cross Join makes my Oracle freeze. Do you know if I can use INner Join instead? My main table has about 2 million records. Honorific table has about 80 records.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT names.lastName
FROM names
INNER JOIN honorophics ON names.lastName LIKE honorophics.listOfHonorophics + '%'
```

this will join the 2 tables, resulting in the rows, where lastName contains a pattern from the table with honorophics